# Bash: Substituting multiline pattern for another

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Sat I have a file that contains the following passage in it:

```
### END: HEADER ###

### BEGIN: OPERATING SYSTEM ###
```

and I wish to replace it with:

```
### END: HEADER ###

### BEGIN: SECURITY ###
Retrieve /Extra/Keys/Root.key
Set SecurityStatus=1
### END: SECURITY ###

### BEGIN: OPERATING SYSTEM ###
```

How do I do this using Bash tools? Would I use awk, grep, sed, or some combination of the three? What be the code to perform the above example?

Comment: grep is for finding patterns on single lines. sed is for simple substitutions on single lines. awk is the standard UNIX general purpose text manipulation tool. Since your problem relates to multiple lines you should use awk and since you are using awk you do not need to additionally use sed and/or grep.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '/HEADER/r file2.txt' file1.txt
```

file1.txt

```
### END: HEADER ###

### BEGIN: OPERATING SYSTEM ###
```

file2.txt

```
### BEGIN: SECURITY ###
Retrieve /Extra/Keys/Root.key
Set SecurityStatus=1
### END: SECURITY ###
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do that. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v add='
### BEGIN: SECURITY ###
Retrieve /Extra/Keys/Root.key
Set SecurityStatus=1
### END: SECURITY ###' '{print} /### END: HEADER ###/{print add}' file
### END: HEADER ###

### BEGIN: SECURITY ###
Retrieve /Extra/Keys/Root.key
Set SecurityStatus=1
### END: SECURITY ###

### BEGIN: OPERATING SYSTEM ###
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `i` (insert) in `sed`:

```
sed -i~ -e '/### BEGIN: OPERATING SYSTEM ###/i### BEGIN: SECURITY ###\
Retrieve /Extra/Keys/Root.key\
Set SecurityStatus=1\
### END: Security ###\

' file
```

Comment: @Zulu: IF there is a problem, you'll have a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how strict you want to be, you may have to implement a parser for this format.  Here is an Awk version which is slightly more strict than the hitherto posted `sed` solutions -- it will bail out if the line two lines after the `END: HEADER` pattern is not `BEGIN: OPERATING SYSTEM`, and the line between isn't empty.

```
awk '/^### END: HEADER ###$/ { i=2; print; next }
    i==2 { if ($0 ~ /^$/) i--; else i=0 }
    i==1 && /^### BEGIN: OPERATING SYSTEM ###$/ {
        print; print "### BEGIN: SECURITY ###"; 
        print "Retrieve /Extra/Keys/Root.key"
        print "Set SecurityStatus=1"
        print "### END: SECURITY ###"; print ""; i=0; next }
    1' file
```

This demonstrates how to generate the desired output on standard output.  Once you are confident that it works, you can wrap it in something like

```
awk '...' file >.file.new && mv .file.new file
```

to replace the original file with the edited version.

Comment: I gave this a try and it doesn't work right. It outputs the added text followed by two lines of "### BEGIN: OPERATING SYSTEM ###" without "### END: HEADER ###". That and it also prepends the contents of the file to the output stream, something which I wouldn't expect to see in a program made for editing text files.

Comment: It works for me with a simple sample which I constructed out of the problem statement you posted.  Can you include a link to a file (say, on https://pastebin.com/) where it doesn't work for you?

Comment: I updated to add a missing `next` from the big block, though -- thanks for the problem report.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^### END: HEADER ###$/!b;n;/^\s*$/!b;n;/^### BEGIN: OPERATING SYSTEM ###$/i\### BEGIN: SECURITY ###\nRetrieve /Extra/Keys/Root.key\nSet SecurityStatus=1\n### END: SECURITY ###\n' file
```

Read and print out exactly 3 lines as specified and insert the required string before the third line.